# Best way to design Android UI?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. Is there a quicker/better way to design the UI than to explicitly write it in XML? Perhaps an Eclipse plug-in to visually create UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better you do with XML. in eclipse you can also put buttons and other views in your layout by simply dragging them in layout.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what sort of UI. If it's something very basic, just buttons and stuff, then you could apply for the app inventor, though it's a few week wait apparently.

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/

Though that's different to best, I'd say XML is definitely the best, or if it's overly simple, then even code. You just need to get used to using XML, it is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say stick with XML.  But if you're interested in a GUI drag/drop way of doing things, you could try [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/).  It's not perfect but for very basic things it might get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

@DroidDraw is not truly wyswyg, but the output is almost what you want to have at the end: some minor tweaks of the resulting .xml layout.